# Change html layout of page based on Tagify tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have a tagify input where for each tag that is added I have a dropdown box to specify some rating for that tag. Say 1-5.

```
<input id="generic-skills" class="tagify" tabindex="-1"/>
```

```
let genericSkillsInput = document.querySelector("#generic-skills");
    let genericSkills = new Tagify(genericSkillsInput, {
        whitelist: [],
        maxTags: 10,            // <- maximum allowed selected tags
        dropdown: {
            maxItems: 10,       // <- maxumum allowed rendered suggestions
            enabled: 0,         // <- show suggestions on focus
            closeOnSelect: true // <- do not hide the suggestions dropdown once an item has been selected
        }
    });
```

I want to then have a list of dropdown boxes below this list that is modified every time a tag is added/removed.

```
<div id="generic-skills-dropdowns" class="offset-1 col-sm-4 pad-all">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>tag name</label>
        <select class="form-control kt-select2" id="kt_select2_2" name="param">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that I can have an event handler like so:

```
async function onGenericSkillsTagsChange(e) {
    const {name, value} = e.target;

    const dropdowns = $('#generic-skills-dropdowns');
    const newDropdown =
        "<div class='form-group'>\n" +
        "    <label>"+ name +"</label>\n" +
        "    <select class='form-control kt-select2' id='kt_select2_2' name='param'>\n" +
        "        <option>1</option>\n" +
        "        <option>2</option>\n" +
        "        <option>3</option>\n" +
        "    </select>\n" +
        "</div>";
    dropdowns.append(newDropdown);
}

genericSkills.DOM.originalInput.addEventListener('change', onGenericSkillsTagsChange);
```

but this doesn't specify whether a tag was added or removed, just gives a list of all current tags. So how can I keep track of which tags are in the input?

Comment: *`how can I keep track of which tags are in the input?`* - `tagify.value`

Answer (score 2):

[Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#events) has [events](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#events) which you can listen, for example the `add` event, so you can know a tag was just added and act.

Keep in mind that a tag may be edited (by *double-click*) so you would want to ask again for rating afterwards or disallow editing (see [settings](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#settings)).

### Example 1 - rating inside the suggestions

If you are forcing your users to select tags from a whitelist, then you can do something cooler, which is to place the rating directly in the suggestions items. You can also only allow selecting a suggestion after it was rated.

Please view below only in ***full-page*** (after clicking `run`):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input')

var tagify = new Tagify(input, {
  addTagOnBlur: false,
  enforceWhitelist: true,
  dropdown: {
    enabled: 0,
    closeOnSelect: true
  },
  whitelist: ['aaa','aaaaaa','aaabbb', 'aaaccc', 'aaadd', 'aaaeee'],
  templates : {
        dropdownItem( item ){
        var uid = `rate-${item.value.replace(/' '/g, '-')}`;
            return `<div ${this.getAttributes(item)}
                      class='tagify__dropdown__item ${item.class ? item.class : ""}'
                      tabindex="0"
                      role="option">
                    ${item.value}
                    <div class="rating" data-value="${item.value}">
                      <input type='radio' hidden name='${uid}' id='${uid}--5' value='5'>    
                      <label for='${uid}--5'></label>

                      <input type='radio' hidden name='${uid}' id='${uid}--4' value='4'>    
                      <label for='${uid}--4'></label>

                      <input type='radio' hidden name='${uid}' id='${uid}--3' value='3'>    
                      <label for='${uid}--3'></label>

                      <input type='radio' hidden name='${uid}' id='${uid}--2' value='2'>    
                      <label for='${uid}--2'></label>

                      <input type='radio' hidden name='${uid}' id='${uid}--1' value='1'>    
                      <label for='${uid}--1'></label>
                    </div>
              </div>`
          }
  },
  hooks: {
    suggestionClick(e){
      var isAction = e.target.closest('.rating'),
          rating = e.target.previousElementSibling.value,
          suggestionElm = e.target.closest('.tagify__dropdown__item'),
          value = suggestionElm.getAttribute('value');

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if( isAction && rating ){
          rateItem(value, rating)
          reject() // prevents selecting this suggestion
        }
        resolve()
      })
    }
  }
})



function rateItem(value, rating){
  // do something...
  console.clear()
  console.log('rated', value, rating, 'stars');   
}
```

```css
.tagify__dropdown__item{
  display: flex;
}

/* star rating - per suggestion */
.rating {
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -2px;
  color: silver;
}
.rating label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rating label::before {
  content: "\2606";
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s;
}

.rating label:hover::before, 
.rating label:hover ~ *::before {
  color: orange;
  opacity: .6;
}
 
.rating input:checked ~ label::before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<input>
```

### Example 2 - rating when tag is added or clicked-on

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input')

var tagify = new Tagify(input, {
  addTagOnBlur: false,
  editTags: false,
  dropdown: {
    enabled: 0,
  },
  whitelist: ['aaa','aaaaaa','aaabbb', 'aaaccc', 'aaadd', 'aaaeee']
})

tagify.on('add click', act)
// tagify.on('remove', onTagRemoved)

function act(e){
  // show rating component now...
  console.clear()
  console.log(e.detail.data);   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<input>
```